# Looping through a JSON Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Okay so I'm given a large JSON Object from a GET request and it looks like this:

```
{
    "partners": [
        {
            "firstName": "Mai",
            "lastName": "Dost",
            "email": "mdost@hubspotpartners.com",
            "country": "United States",
            "availableDates": [
                "2017-05-29",
                "2017-05-31",
                "2017-06-01",
                "2017-06-07",
                "2017-06-08",
                "2017-06-09",
                "2017-06-11",
                "2017-06-12"
            ]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Annamae",
            "lastName": "Monty",
            "email": "amonty@hubspotpartners.com",
            "country": "United States",
            "availableDates": [
                "2017-05-31",
                "2017-06-01",
                "2017-06-07",
                "2017-06-08",
                "2017-06-09",
                "2017-06-11",
                "2017-06-12",
                "2017-06-15",
                "2017-06-16",
                "2017-06-20"
            ]
        },
```

I'm trying to scan through all the individual partners in this object but I can't seem to get anything returned other than "undefined". I'm using a for loop to try go into each value and I've asked it to alert me each time so I can see it's contents. Can you guys see what I'm doing wrong?

The JavaScript code for this is:

```
$.getJSON("someURL_IcantDisclose", function (result) {
  var data = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
  document.getElementById('load').innerHTML = data;
  for(var i=0; i<data.partners.length;i++){
    alert(data.partners[i]);
  }
});
```

Comment: Do you mean "JSON array" or "array"? The former is a string (JSON is a string format), the latter is an... array. You `stringify` and then try to access the string as if it was an object?

Comment: That's neither a _JSON Array_ nor a _JSON Object_. That (`result`) is an object with properties which happen to be arrays. The only "real" JSON involved in your example is stored in `data` (and somewhere in `$.getJSON()` but you can't work with that directly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what these two lines are doing `var data = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);document.getElementById('load').innerHTML = data;`, but the following snippet will allow you to loop over the `partners`

```
$.getJSON("someURL_IcantDisclose", function (result) {
  for(var i=0; i<result.partners.length; i++){
    alert(result.partners[i]);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You are attempting to loop over the strinigified version of the result - `$.getJSON` will return the parsed JSON so you can use `result` directly:

```
$.getJSON("someURL_IcantDisclose", function (result) {
  for(var i=0; i< result.partners.length; i++){
    alert(result.partners[i]);
  }
});
```